# ExtJS - gridpanel all check

Tags: javascript, extjs3, gridpanel

I have a question... If you know this, please write reple...

When I click the most up check button - common check button, all items checked or unchecked in gridpanel...

Is it possible?

If you don't understand, you can see common website email page...

When it is not ExtJS, I can do it. (Javascript) but I wondered it does in ExtJS too.

Please help me... Thanks!

Comment: no idea whats being asked here. code, link or something ...

Comment: I want to show a image, but I'm new user so I can't upload image...

Answer (score 1):

here you check that following link you will find the answer for your ques

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html